# How to resolve thread issues with java and mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, concurrency

I am working on a project that has legacy Java code. It uses mysql, and the project has no thread policy in locking the mysql resources and thread visibility issues. Different people contributed to the codebase, everyone has locked the resources as they wanted, and now we scaled a lot, now we get all sorts of issues (deadlock, thread visibility issues).

My management is not intended to rewrite the code base atleast in the near future. I am trying to fix the issues as much as I can. Its painful that going through the logs and replicating the exact issue and fixing them.

Is there a better way to fix the threading issues? I can not use opensource tools like findbug or anyother concurrency tools because we use table level locking.

My solution is to log all the queries made by each class, and rewrite the flow into an equivalent java class, and use the opensource tools/manual investigation to figure out the issue. I dont know if its a better way to handle the issue.

Comment: Could you post an example of one of the current issues? Sorry if this sounds demanding, but adding code can help us understand the real problem.

Comment: I'd use a concurrent data source if you are not already.  See: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: How does concurrent datasource will help me?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I cannot post the code, but for example the code does not lock a table before updating the values over there, and we use repeatable read. Other thread could see the stale data, and fails because of stale data. Like this it seems like we might have lot of potential issues, I need a way to find automatically figure out the issues say atleast 50% without manual code walkthrough.

Comment: I don't think locking the whole table will solve your problems (in fact, you will notice performance problems when changing that). I would really ask if you can provide a real problem instead of just telling us to try guessing what your problems are.